# UWP don't want to execute process as admin

Tags: c#, uwp, process, shellexecute

I have code:

```
// Execute msi
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(msiPath);
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"  /passive /i {Path.GetFileName(msiPath)}";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

But I have error:

> UseShellExecute is not supported on this platform.

Or if I disable UseShellExecute

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Programm doesn't execute because of admin privileges

Sooo... How can I execute msi as admin in UWP?

Comment: this is not possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute

Comment: @ChrisBerlin I have to disagree with you. For some UWP apps in menu I can click "run as administrator". If I can't dynamically request permissions, in theory I can start app with admin permissions. But I don't know - how to make it in practice

Comment: Please check the API documentation that Chris Berlin posted, it clearly mentions that set the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property will raise a **PlatformNotSupportedException** if you do it in UWP apps. The behavior you got is expected.

Comment: Another thing is that you can't execute msi from a UWP app. Please try it on WPF or Win32 app.

Comment: You can't directly do it from UWP - you'd have to set up a different exe in the same install folder to pass through as a workaround as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189353/uwp-how-to-start-an-exe-file-that-is-located-in-specific-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is mentioned here-[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-5.0) that set the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property will raise a PlatformNotSupportedException if you do it in UWP apps. The behavior you got is expected. Second, [Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0) is not supported in UWP apps. To run the exe file from your UWP app, I'd suggest you use [FullTrustProcessLauncher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-20348).

First, you need to copy the exe file and save it in the UWP app package, for example, the Assets folder. Then please go to the Manifest file and add the **runFullTrust restricted capability**.([App capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)). Next, add the reference of **Windows Desktop Extensions** for the UWP project. At last, you could call `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();` to launch the exe file from your app.